# Google maps default zoom changed?

Tags: google-maps

I used to have a part of a web page for a venue display a map:

```
<iframe width="934" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/?q=loc:36.12829973975456,-115.16433477401732&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=36.12829973975456,-115.16433477401732&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Example of the complete page is here:
http://www.nationalvip.com/venue/4a9248d6f964a520091d20e3/xs-nightclub

This used to render to a pretty decent default street view.  Somehow now I get the whole globe displayed and wrapped around.  Any guesses as to what can be going on?  Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Have you checked here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide?  You may need to revise the URL and add an API key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened to your link, but the following should work

```
<iframe width="934" height="200" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/place/36%C2%B007'41.9%22N+115%C2%B009'51.6%22W/@36.128279,-115.164285,39m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en-US"></iframe>
```

It is a satellite view, not a Google Street View, but Street View may not be available for those coordinates.